# How do I deploy a MERN stack application to cpanel on a VPS server

Tags: deployment, hosting, cpanel, vps, mern

Please anybody with the experience of deploying a MERN stack APP to cpanel on a VPS server? Kindly share! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload an app to cpanel, that is developed using node,express and react (and in this case, you must ensure first that the cpanel supports nodejs apps, not all of them do so). But, mongoDB simply is not supported by CPanel. You can upload MERN stack app, but, the db won't be connected.

1. Once you have the cpanel access, create a folder to the directory, upload your project (make sure you take the integrated approach to deploy your mern app).
2. Go to the UI, create an app and address the folder to the app. Start the app. And your website is ready to use.

Comment: I wanted to upload MERN stack project to whm/cpanel ubuntu server. 
For connecting MongoDB, do you mean I have to use mongodb atlas service?
And how can I check the cpanel support nodejs app?